# Accessing browser API through Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox-addon

I thought to make a firefox addon with Vue.js and wanted to use the API from the browser. For example to use `browser.tabs` or `browser.dns`. But when I use browser in the script part of a component I get the output that `'browser' is not defined`.

Is it possible to access the API of the browser with vuejs?

Comment: I'm not sure, but so far: `browser` and `window` (used on client-side) are 2 different contexts. I doubt it's possible to use `browser` in a Vue context (may be wrong).

Comment: Whether you use Vue or not doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

[`browser.tabs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) and [`browser.dns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns) are part of the Browser Extensions API. And Vue *can* be used to create browser extensions, so yes, it's possible to use that API from Vue.

For example, [`vitesse-webext`](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-webext) is a starter template for creating cross-platform (including Chrome and Firefox) browser extensions with Vue.